# Parsing Text String

Tags: command-line, lua

I have created a running windows process list to a text file using the command:

> tasklist > c:\mytasklist.txt. The result something like this:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
System                           4 Services                   0     12.408 K
smss.exe                       320 Services                   0      1.236 K
csrss.exe                      424 Services                   0      4.720 K
wininit.exe                    516 Services                   0      4.684 K
csrss.exe                      524 Console                    1      7.888 K
winlogon.exe                   572 Console                    1      7.764 K
services.exe                   620 Services                   0      9.532 K

and so on...
```

My question:
How I parsing the line on the text file, so I get output like the following format using Lua script:

1. PID - Process Name - Memory Usage
2. And the output automatic sorted by the biggest memory usage

Comment: Try `tasklist /fo csv /nh` to make the output more easy to parse

Comment: tasklist /fo csv /nh to make the output more easy to parse – @Egor Skriptunoff; it returns the result, eq: "System Idle Process","0","Services","0","24 K"...and son on. How or what regex use to parsing the result as  only : name-pid-mem.usage?

Answer (score 0):

```
local tasklist = io.popen"tasklist /fo csv /nh"
local list = {}
for line in tasklist:lines() do
   local exe, pid, mem = line:match'^"(.-)","(%d+)",.-"([^"]+)"$'
   table.insert(list, {pid = tonumber(pid), exe = exe, mem = tonumber((mem:gsub("%D", "")))})
end
tasklist:close()
table.sort(list, function(a, b) return a.mem > b.mem end)
for j = 1, math.min(10, #list) do
   print(list[j].pid, list[j].mem, list[j].exe)
end
```

Output:

```
1036  549416  svchost.exe
4972  439524  firefox.exe
6540  214476  plugin-container.exe
7144  169268  OUTLOOK.EXE
532   75320   svchost.exe
1948  71644   avp.exe
3752  62704   svchost.exe
5268  61100   explorer.exe
596   56732   csrss.exe
5048  50248   CcmExec.exe
```

Comment: Great!. Work properly and I use it on my script